# How to find sum of integers generated in a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, sum

```
salary = 1000
interest = 0.002 * salary
x = 0
while x < 12:
    yes = 0.15 * salary
    salary += interest
    x += 1
```

Above is what I have
I would like to print the sum of yes after the loop is done, I tried 
y = yes += yes
print(y) this didn't work

Comment: `yes+=yes` won't work as you are re-initializing the variable yes in the start of the loop

Comment: You should consider using a for-loop since you know the starting and ending index, and increment of the loop

Answer (score 1):

```
salary = 1000
interest = 0.002 * salary
x = 0
sum_of_yes=0
while x < 12:
    yes = 0.15 * salary
    salary += interest
    x += 1
    sum_of_yes+=yes

print sum_of_yes
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set `yes` to zero before the loop you can just `+=` it:

```
salary = 1000
interest = 0.002 * salary
x = 0
yes = 0
while x < 12:
    yes += 0.15 * salary
    salary += interest
    x += 1
print(yes)
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be better accomplished in a `for` loop rather than a `while`:

```py
salary = 1000
interest = .002 * salary
x, total_yes = 0, 0

# This will keep track of x for you
for x in range(12):
    yes = 0.15 * salary
    salary += interest
    total_yes += yes

print(total_yes)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I would use list comprehension combined with a function:

```
salary = 1000
interest = 0.002

def sum_yes(salary, interest):
    monthly_interest = 0.002 * salary
    monthly_salaries = [salary + (monthly_interest * month) for month in range(12)]
    return sum([month_salary * 0.15 for month_salary in monthly_salaries])

yes = sum_yes(salary, interest)
print(yes)
```